# Issuing Octave/Matlab Command from LAMP

Tags: php, python

Is it possible to execute Octave/Matlab command from user interaction in web page so that, if a client issues like a button like with some input value from client page, the server can issue octave/matlab command and print the result back to client?

Comment: Use `exec` or `system` in PHP, containing the console command you would normally use to kick this off. You might have to tweak it to use full paths to Matlab binaries though.

Comment: (I've removed a few tags, as the question isn't really about Matlab etc - I think your general question is asking about how to run a console command? You may wish to specify PHP or Python though - presumably if your web app is written in one, the other isn't going to be very useful).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about deploying Matlab code in PHP & Python, but for [Java](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) & .NET, refer [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.in/desktop-web-deployment/deploying-code-web-application.html). 
There are a lot of other resources on internet like [Matlab web server](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/access/helpdesk_r13/help/toolbox/webserver/ch01intr.html), converting Matlab code into C and so...., so please [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20use%20matlab%20in%20web%20apps) for more (Note: MIT has some best resources).